# Everytime I try to do updates via the update manager it prompts me to enter my password

Tags: 10.10, gnome, update-manager

So I do, and then it just hangs there, from there I can close the box using the "X" in the corner, then the update will continue, I am guessing this is not the intended behavior, any ideas as to what is going on?

I can update fine using the terminal... just not using the update manager.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am using 10.10

Comment: Does **apt-get upgrade** work?

Comment: yes, this works

Comment: Do you first check for new updates before trying to install them?

Comment: yes, and I have also skipped checking for updates to see if there was any difference, there is not.

Comment: I've seen it, but only through a remote connection (using NoMachine). When connected "for real", the problem disapeared :-(

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of this?

Comment: actually it has seemed to resolve itself... must have just been a broken update...

Comment: This happened to me a lot, it seems to be a bug related to the policykit dialog, I didn't file a bug report yet because I am unable to reliably reproduce it.

Comment: This was happening to me a while back. I found clicking "check" and then "install" worked each time it had gone inactive. Not that that fixes that cause of the problem of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I have the same issue. Also, since you can update from the terminal just fine, then it must be a problem with `update-manager`. Since that's the problem, then just run `sudo update-manager` next time you update, and if it happens copy and past the output into paste.ubuntu.com. And also, to update from the terminal it's `sudo apt-get upgrade`, just for future reference. `sudo apt-get update` updates the package list from the repositories list.

Answer (score 1):

I would run update manager from the terminal then you can grab a copy of the messages in the terminal then you can paste the result at paste.ubuntu.com and post the link in your original question (you can edit it) this will show if it is a bug in the update manager package or possibly some where else. Plus make a note of the time when you start the proccess as it will make it easier to find any errors which relate to the action in your logs which are in Administration -> Log viewer.

the command for update manager is.

```
update-manager
```

Hope this helps